# extract element before UPPERCASE

Tags: python, regex, string, uppercase

I have this following string :

```
text = '6 rue du Bras de Fer MONTPELLIER France'
```

I'd like to extract only **"6 rue du Bras de Fer"**
I am trying to use regex to extract this part, this my regex code :

```
re.findall(r'(.*)[A-Z]+',text)
```

but it returns me :

```
['6 rue du Bras de Fer MONTPELLIER ']
```

Comment: `re.split(r'\s*\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', text)[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Lookaheads are made for this:

```
re.findall(r'^(.*)(?=\s+[A-Z]{2})',text)
```

This matches before at least two uppercase letters after whitespace.

Comment: postprocessing is required though: result `['6 rue du Bras de Fer', '']`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

You may extract all up to the first word that only consists of two or more uppercase letters:

```
m = re.search(r'^(.*?)\s*\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 6 rue du Bras de Fer
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S2cezH/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2dIQRo).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Z]{2,}` - two or more uppercase letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code:

```
import re
text = '6 rue du Bras de Fer MONTPELLIER France'
re.findall(r'(.*)[a-z]+ ',text)
```

You must change `A` to `a` and `Z` to `z` in `[A-Z]`. Also, you need a `space` in end of your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking the real solution is to extract before Uppercase, all before the
last Uppercase that does not have an Uppercase either *before* nor *after* it.

`(?:[^A-Z]|(?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z]))+(?=[A-Z])`

https://regex101.com/r/9vpFjj/1

Expanded

```
 (?:
      [^A-Z] 
   |  
      (?<! [A-Z] )
      [A-Z] 
      (?! [A-Z] )
 )+
 (?= [A-Z] )
```